# US Tax Form 1040EZ: Do I enter ALL income or ONLY income specified in W-2 forms?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, form-1040

When filling out form 1040EZ, the very first line alludes to form W-2 as the source of the total amount of my income for the year.

However, aside from my W-2 form, I had some income from freelance work that was simply paid to me directly via PayPal.

**Can I just enter my total income from all sources and file the form?**

If so, do I still attach only my W-2 form (which means the amount in the 1040EZ form will be different from the amount specified in my W-2)? Or do I have to print out and attach proof of all the other income (such as PayPal activity) as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need to include income from your freelance work on your tax return.  In the eyes of the IRS, this is self-employment income from your sole-proprietorship business.

The reason you don't see it mentioned in the 1040EZ instructions is that you can't use the 1040EZ form if you have self-employment income.  You'll need to use the full [1040 form](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-form-1040).  Your business income and expenses will be reported on a [Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/uac/schedule-c-form-1040-profit-or-loss-from-business) or [Schedule C-EZ](https://www.irs.gov/uac/schedule-c-ez-form-1040-net-profit-from-business), and the result will end up on Line 12 of the 1040.  Take a look at the requirements at the top of the C-EZ form; you probably meet them and can use it instead of the more complicated C form.

If you have any deductible business expenses related to your freelance business, this would be done on Schedule C or C-EZ.

If your freelance income was more than $400, you'll also need to pay self-employment tax.  To do this, you file [Schedule SE](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-schedule-se-form-1040), and the tax from that schedule lands on form 1040 Line 57.